# Flutter null safety migration

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm recently migrating an application from Flutter 3.7.0 to 3.10.6 in which they now ask me to use null safety, have I placed the operators? to indicate that certain variables can be null but when validating said variables in an if statement it tells me that the operator cannot be null

```
class IsoField {
  int? field;
  String? description;
  String? contentType;
  LT? lengthType;
  DT? lengthDataType;
  DT? dataType;
  int? maxLength;

  IsoField(this.field, {this.description, this.contentType, this.lengthDataType, this.dataType, this.maxLength, this.lengthType});
}

String? description(int? field, [String? description]) {
    IsoField? currentField = this.fields.firstWhere((e) => e.field == field, orElse: null);
    int index = this.fields.indexOf(currentField);

    if (description == null) {
      if (currentField!=null) { //The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'true'. Remove the condition.
        return this.fields[index].description!;
      } else
        return null;
    } else {
      if (currentField==null) {
        IsoField temp = new IsoField(field, description: description);
        this.fields.add(temp);
        return temp.description;
      } else
        return this.fields[index].description;
    }
  }
```

I also tried using the .isNull and .isDefineAndNotNull property but it tells me that:

Error: Dart library 'dart:js_interop' is not available on this platform.
8583specs.dart:2
import 'dart:js_interop';

Comment: Please post the exact error message and the line it appears in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks very convoluted. Isn't it just this?

```
String? description(int? field, [String? description]) {
  IsoField? currentField = this.fields.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.field == field);

  if (currentField != null) {
    return currentField.description;
  }

  if (description != null) {  
    this.fields.add(new IsoField(field, description: description));
  }

  return description;
}
```

That should work fine with null safety.

Comment: It worked by adding firstWhereOrNull, and I know that the code is complicated since it has not been updated since version 3.0.2 of flutter, they made me do the update to familiarize myself with flutter